# Google Compute RHEL Instance - Peer cert cannot be verified

Tags: google-compute-engine, yum, rhel

I am trying to undertake a yum upgrade on one of my servers and I am getting this error:

Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com/pulp/mirror//client/rhel6/x86_64 error was
14: Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid

I've looked across the internet and the common answer is turn SSL off however this doesn't work either.

https://cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com/pulp/repos/client/rhel6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 
https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623
If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

Has anyone else been experiencing this? What have I been doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide,
Sam

Comment: The 1st link returns an SSL error in firefox, the 2nd link returns 404. What are you trying to install? It maybe another repo better suites your needs

Answer (score -1):

This question was answered the google issue tracker at this URL: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67348923